# Achieve the dynamic field calculation in Power BI using DAX

Tags: mdx, powerbi, percentage, dax, percentile

I have a MDX query that needs to be converted in DAX in Power BI.
MDX:

```
CASE WHEN    ISEMPTY( [Measures].[Total] )
                    THEN NULL
                    ELSE
                IIF(
            ISEMPTY( Axis(1).Item(0).Item(0).Dimension.Levels(0).item(0)),1,
[Measures].[Total]  / ( Axis(1).Item(0).Item (0).Dimension.Levels(0).item(0), [Measures].[Total]  )
                                        )
                                        END
```

I assume that the above query is:
**Total** is Aggregated sum of the data as per month or any dimension and **% Total** is `Total / (The Total of the entire columnar data)`

Please see the below screenshot (Sample data):

[image: Sample data screenshot]

Does anyone know how to achieve the above functionality in Power BI?

Comment: You just want percent of total...I think including that next is overcomplicating things

Comment: Do you want a measure or a calculated column?

Comment: It's a measure column, But I need to get the Total/ Sum of the Total

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a feature in Power BI that shows percent of grand total automatically. Take a look at the screenshots below to get more details
[image: Before]

After applying this fetaure you get something like this
[image: After]

Comment: I've made improvement to the first comment